# how to wait service load data complete?

Tags: angular, async-await

I want to load data from an angular service in a component constructor, and use these data to update the UI in the ngOnInit() function.

I am using the async-await feature to implement it.

Unfortunately, it does not work.

Here is my component source code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MonthlyCalendar} from './monthly-calendar';
import { MonthlyCalendarService } from './monthly-calendar.service';
import { resolve } from 'url';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  monthlyCalendar: MonthlyCalendar;
  constructor(private monthlyCalendarService: MonthlyCalendarService) {
    this.monthlyCalendar = null;
    console.log('t0:' + new Date());
    this._getData();

    console.log('t2:' + new Date());
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('t3:' + new Date());
    console.log(this.monthlyCalendar);
  }
  async _getData() {

    await this.monthlyCalendarService.getMonthlyCalendar(null, null)
    .then((data: MonthlyCalendar) => {
      console.log('t1:' + new Date());
      this.monthlyCalendar = data;
    })
    .catch ((err: Error) => {
      alert(err.stack);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my service source code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MonthlyCalendar } from './monthly-calendar';
import { resolve, reject } from 'q';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MonthlyCalendarService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getMonthlyCalendar(year: number, month: number): Promise<object> {
    const params = new HttpParams();
    if (year != null) {
      params.set('year', year.toString());
    }
    if (month != null) {
      params.set('month', month.toString());
    }
    return this.http.get('backend/getMonthlyCalendar.php', {params}).toPromise();
  }
}
```

Here is my component.html

```
<table>
  <theader></theader>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I attached the screen dump for your reference.

[image]

Comment: can you add your template code ?

Comment: Do you mean the component.html ?

Comment: yes, The code where you are using `monthlyCalendar `

Comment: Currently, I want to ensure the this.monthlyCalendar is not null before ngOnInit(), so the component.html is the initial content only.

Comment: What if I said you couldn’t prevent render. Instead move the retrieval of data to a parent component and use ngIf to only render the component when the data has resolved. Other use ngIf in this component and use some sort of loading animation while the data loads. Move async calls or computationally heavy operations out of constructor.

Comment: I add my component.html for your reference. I want to use this.monthlyCalendar to update both theader and tbody component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Resolvers to load data before component load it will not load the route until data request is resolved below are some example for resolvers

https://codeburst.io/understanding-resolvers-in-angular-736e9db71267

https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/

so first create a resolver like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';

@Injectable()
export class CalendarResolver implements Resolve<Observable<string>> {
  constructor(private monthlyCalendarService: MonthlyCalendarService) {}

  resolve() {
    return this.monthlyCalendarService.getMonthlyCalendar(null, null);
  }
}
```

Then add this resolver to your route

```
import { CalendarResolver } from './claendar.resolver';

   {
    path: 'yourpath',
    component: yourcomponent,
    resolve: { calander: CalendarResolver }
    }
```

**Add your resolvers to providers array of your module**

then in your component

```
   constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute)

   ngOnInit(){
    this.monthlyCalander= this.route.snapshot.data['calander'];
   }
```

Comment: It prompts that node_modules/rxjs/Observable has no exported member 'Observable'.

I am using angular 8.

Comment: @TheKNVB from latest version use `import { Observable } from 'rxjs'`

Comment: i am not sure about this can you add stackblitz example of your problem

Comment: here is working demo of resolver https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-resolver-demo

Comment: I tried to do this for the homepage but I cannot see how I change the (pre-existing?) resolver for that, if I add another route with path: '' for home then it "works" but my app is then duplicated.. like I see all elements twice, footer and header.. I have a new boilerplate angular installation with isomorphic, followed the official installation steps.. In nextjs it's like 5 lines of code in one file... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a resolver for this

```
@Injectable()
export class MyResolver implements Resolve<SomeClass[]> {
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<SomeClass[]> {
        return this.myService.getAll().pipe(first());
    }
}
```

In your router, you can register the resolver.

```
        {
            path: 'somepath',
            component: MyComponent,
            resolve: {
                objects: MyResolver ,
            }
        },
```

Then you can access the resolved data like below in your component.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.data.subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.objects = data['objects'];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the code like this in constructor

```
this._getData().then(() =>  
      console.log('t2:' + new Date()
      ))
```

Comment: The ngOnInit() does not wait for the specified code.

Comment: this code not going to wait to finish the execution. `then` method automatically trigger after `_getDate` execute. you can put what ever coder want execute after `_getDate` in to the `then` method

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a very nice module HTTPClientModule. This is built on the top of RxJS Observable package.

The methods like 'get' of the HTTPClientModule, return observable, which we can subscribe in the components, and notify view to update the DOM.

Please read the official [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http)